how to compare between GAMlSS model using cross-validation
i have a question about how to compare between two gamlss model in R using cross-validation. this is my model
`M3 <- gamlss(rentsqm ~ pb(area) + pb(yearc)  +location*bath * kitchen * cheating, mu.formula= ~pb(area)+ pb(yearc)+ location*bath * kitchen * cheating , sigma.formula = ~pb(area)+ pb(yearc)+ location*bath * kitchen * cheating , nu.formula= ~pb(area)+ pb(yearc)+ location*bath * kitchen * cheating,
                  family =BCCG(mu.link = "identity", sigma.link = "log", nu.link = "identity"), data = data)`

M4 <- gamlss(rentsqm ~ pb(area) + pb(yearc)  +location*bath * kitchen * cheating, mu.formula=~0, sigma.formula = ~1 ,
              family =GU(mu.link = "identity", sigma.link = "log"), data = data)

install.packages("cvms")
library(cvms)

cross_validate <- function(data, M3, M4, k = 10) {
  
  n <- nrow(data)
  
  
  folds <- sample(1:k, n, replace = TRUE)
  
  
  mse1 <- numeric(k)
  mse2 <- numeric(k)
  
  for (i in 1:k) {
    
    test_indices <- which(folds == i)
    train_data <- data[-test_indices, ]
    test_data <- data[test_indices, ]
    
    
    fit1 <- update(M3, data = train_data)
    fit2 <- update(M4, data = train_data)
    
    
    pred1 <- predict(fit1, newdata = test_data)
    pred2 <- predict(fit2, newdata = test_data)
    
    
    true_values <- test_data$rentsqm
    
    
    mse1[i] <- mean((true_values - pred1)^2)
    mse2[i] <- mean((true_values - pred2)^2)
  }
  
  
  mse1_mean <- mean(mse1)
  mse2_mean <- mean(mse2)
  
  return(list(model1_mse = mse1_mean, model2_mse = mse2_mean))
}
results <- cross_validate(data, M3, M4)
print(results)

there is error when i run this code (train_data not found). i dont know if my code correct. thanks alot.
